# How can I customize the first sidebar?

Tags: theming

I am trying to customize the Bartik theme.
How can I customize left sidebar? I want to add some more links, and remove the search fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable the search block in "Structure -> Blocks" in the admin panel. On the same page you can create a new block and add some links to it. Then add the block to the side bar.

Comment: For the links you proabably want to edit an existing menu or create a new one at Structure -> Menus instead of defining them yourself with HTML.